# Can I claim a SuperAnnuation -loss- on my 2011-2012 Australian Tax Office tax return?

Tags: australia, income-tax, superannuation

can i claim any super annuation -loss- in an Australia Tax Office (ATO) tax return? if so, what section please?

Comment: More inforfation is required. What type of super do you have? Do you have a retail or industry fund or do you have a SMSF?

Comment: It's not a Self Managed Super fund, but through an AMP broker. I can log into my super account at the AMP's website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no.

A superannuation fund will have it's own tax return, and any net loses during a financial year will be carried forward to offset superannuation gains in future income years.

If you have a SMSF, then the SMSF will have to complete and lodge its own tax return.